# How can an activity pull a value from a service?

Tags: android, android-service

I have two classes: one is an activity and the other is a class derived from NotificationListenerService.

I need for the activity to be able to obtain the initial value of the device's interruption filter setting and then to be notified if it changes.

So the activity is listening to broadcasts made by the NLS for when the value of the interruption filter changes. 
However, I need to get the initial value of the interruption filter - if the user never changes this value then my activity will never get a broadcast so it will never find out what the value is.

So my question is how can the activity request a value from a service?

Note that NotificationListenerService is started by the OS, it is not something my activity creates nor starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SharedPreferences to store some value (in service) and your activity could act depending on it by loading the value from SharedPreferences.
Also you could use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and pass some event using it. The way should be like this:
- your Activity register EventBus for catching some speacial Event instead of NLS.
- Notifications Service generates and posts an Event when it needs to. It also packages any data your activity needs into an Event
- your Activity catches a new Event from NS and obtains data from it:

```
public void onEvent(final FriendsRenameEvent event) {
    Log.i(this, "onEvent() FriendsRenameEvent event");
    if (event.isActionSucced)
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

the event is just a simeple class (extends Object):

```
public class FriendsRenameEvent {

    public final boolean isActionSucced;

    public FriendsRenameEvent(final boolean isSucced/*, final Contact rejectedContact*/) {
        this.isActionSucced = isSucced;
    }
}
```

Im using it for GCM like this (part of a GCMIntenService):

```
private void handleMessage(final Bundle gcmBundle) {
    if (gcmBundle == null) {
        Log.e(this, "handleMessage(): Received null-gcmBundle in GCMIntentService.onReceive()!");
        return;
    }

    Log.i(this, "handleMessage(): gcmBundle: " + gcmBundle);

    EventBus.getDefault().post(new IncomingGCMEvent(gcmBundle));
}
```

And in Activity:

```
public void onEventMainThread(final IncomingGCMEvent event) {
   final String payloadMessage = event.gcmBundle.getString("collapse_key");
   ...
}
```

Also there is a Bind mechanism to bind services and activities together. Using Bind interface you could run methods of a Sevice from an Activity like its an Activity's own methods.

Comment: How would a service publishing things via a broadcast differ from it publishing things via events? I mean its still a pushing design, but I need the activity to pull. Or can eventbus provide pull functionality?  Thanks for the suggestion about SharedPreferences, that might be an easy solution.

Comment: NotificationListenerService could preoduce an Event and your Activity catches that Event. No pull is needed. You could include anything you want into  an Event. So when Activity receives an Event it could "pull" desired data from it. Had you ever tried EventBus at all? If not give it a try, I'd linked its GitHub

Comment: NLS seems special - only the OS can bind to it. And also the NLS gets started by the OS before the activity gets created therefore the activity doesn't have the chance to set up listeners etc. in time to catch an initial output from the service (otherwise the service could produce something via a broadcast or an event etc. in its onListenerConnected, but that's too early and it'll be missed by the activity).

Comment: Seems like a best way here is to use EventBus.